# pgfplotsforeachungrouped with >2 entries

Tags: pgfplots, macros, foreach

I'm having trouble understanding why `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` is breaking in certain spots.

Why does this work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\def\macroOne#1{
    #1
    }

\def\macroTwo#1{
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x/\y in {#1}{
    \macroOne{\x}
}
}

\begin{document}
    \macroTwo{%
        1/2%
        }%
\end{document}
```

But this doesn't?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\def\macroOne#1{
    #1
    }

\def\macroTwo#1{
    \pgfplotsforeachungrouped \x/\y/\z in {#1}{
    \macroOne{\x}
}
}

\begin{document}
    \macroTwo{%
        1/2/3%
        }%
\end{document}
```

The only difference between the two is that I added in one more sub-argument into `\MacroTwo` and the `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped`. Is there a way to make `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` work for more than two sub-arguments?

Comment: It looks as if it can handle only two variables. But you should really consider to switch to the code @egreg suggested to your other question. With expl3 such list processing is much easier -- less \expandafter and lots of useful functions available out of the box.

Comment: Ulrike is right. `\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` can handle only two variables. I am pretty sure that there was a question on TeX.SX already about that topic, but couldn't find it ... But in the PGFPlotsToDo.pdf one can find a bug which states: "`\pgfplotsforeachungrouped` cannot be combined with three or more arguments like `\foreach`."